# PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA BSOD with second monitor on laptop, Do I have bad RAM?

Tags: windows, memory, crash, bsod

I only started getting this BSOD after I started using a second monitor regularly on my laptop. My machine is a Dell Vostro 1500. Core 2 Duo T5270 1.4 Ghz CPU, 2 Gigs PC5300 (667 MHz). I do not have a dedicated graphics card but have a Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset. I am running Windows XP Home SP3 with all updates.

I have analyzed the crash dumps using Windbg and found the offending driver to be `Probably caused by : prcmondrv1041.sys ( prcmondrv1041+f5d )`. Exactly what process is running changes but the most common offender is the IDriveE Service. The other program that I know of that caused the BSOD was a remote desktop program called ShowMyPC which is based on VNC.

When I had the service set to start automatically, it would crash before it was finished logging in. I could see the desktop but not all of the services and startup applications were loaded yet. To add an interesting twist, it would only crash when it was plugged in, not when running on battery.

Here is some info from the minidump analysis that may be interesting. I can add more if someone thinks it would be helpful.

```
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffe8, memory referenced.
Arg2: 00000001, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: 804de948, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory address.
Arg4: 00000000, (reserved)
```

I have run MemTest86+ but it found no errors. I also did a virus scan but again, nothing was found.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling PRC View (from a quick google I am assuming this is the program you are using)?  Also would be worth checking your graphics drivers are up to date or possible just reinstalling those to see if that helps.

Comment: It is not a program that I am using, but I have used it in the past. There is no uninstall available. I would be tempted to think it is a virus except for the fact that the virus scanner turns up nothing and that all the version numbers and other file properties all look legit. I updated graphics, chipset and BIOS drivers...still crashing. I removed one of my 1G sticks of RAM and I can no longer get it to crash...interesting. Also, when I disabled my second monitor it didn't crash. I am feeling pretty confident this isn't a virus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver prcmondrv1041.sys seems to be a part of the PrcView process viewer utility which displays detailed information about processes running under Windows.

I would suggest to uninstall PrcView and see if the problems persists.
If you need a process viewer, the free [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is the best of its kind and doesn't use a system driver.

If you don't have PrcView installed, then this is a virus. Perhaps then your getting infected just coincided with getting the second monitor. I would suggest several scans by well-known antivirus products (beware of fakes). I would suggest doing this in any case.

**EDIT**

The real PrcView is supposed to uninstallable via the Control Panel.
So your problem becomes more and more puzzling as time goes on.

I suggest trying [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) on it, and if all else fails than using Process Explorer and [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to find out which .exe files and service files are used.

[Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) is excellent for removing viruses.
You can also use an 
antivirus online scan such as [Trend Micro House Call](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/) and [Kaspersky Labs Free Virus Scan](http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner). Please note that they might require you to use Internet Explorer as your browser and that each scan may take several hours.

Comment: See comment above. I don't get the error when my second monitor is disabled.

Comment: @Jeffreymb: As 1st step I would say to get rid of the product that seems to cause the problem, and continue with other solutions if it seems that windbg was wrong about its cause.

Comment: You can disable that driver without uninstalling the product. Open the registry editor (WIn-R , regedit) and browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services . ctrl-F for Find, Find what: prcmondrv for the find target, leave everything checked except "match whole string only". Click Find Next. This should get you to a key that includes that name. Also the "ImagePath" value should match the driver name. Now double-click on the "Start" value in the right pane. Change the value to 4, which means disabled. Reboot and the driver should be disabled from loading.